# Minimum number sticks requirement

Tags: geometry

> A box of sticks of equal lengths is provided.
>
> The minimum number sticks needed to build a frame to enclose a 3 dimensional volume is
>
> 1. 6
> 2. 12
> 3. 3
> 4. 8

#### Solution:

2) We can make cube with the help of  12 sticks.

It will definitely enclose  3 dimensional figure.

1) Also with the help of 6 sticks I can make tetrahedron

Here 3 sticks are require to make base

Also with other 3 sticks, its top is formed

I think it is the answer

3) According to me, it is not possible

4) It is rejected as I make 3 dimensional figure in option (1)

But suggest me the 3 dimensional figure formed by 8 sticks.

Am I doing right?

Comment: I'd say you did a good job!

Comment: This question is under-specified. What is a frame, and what is the volume that it encloses? Also, your second "4)" should be "2)".

Comment: Thanks , I corrected the mistake.

Comment: I think frame means any arrangement of sticks which can be used for enclosing 3D volume.

Comment: As in question "a 3 dimensional volume" is given . So this means any 3D volume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that a tetrahedron can be made with six sticks, so can ignore the choices 8 and 12.  There doesn't have to be a solid with 8 sticks for the answer to be 6.  But you can make one-a pyramid with a square base.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. Its really helpful